# How can I add user consent in keycloak with create user or other API(s)?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using keycloak API:

> http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users for creating user

it's working fine but I need to add user consent with this API or by any alternative API(s), How can I do this,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, although I am not 100% it will work:

If you look at the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation) you can see that for the endpoint:

```
POST /{realm}/users
```

which is the endpoint that you are using to create the users you can pass the following body parameters:

```
UserRepresentation
```

which is composed by (among others) the following (optional) field :

```
clientConsents <UserConsentRepresentation> array
```

Therefore, you can create the user already with its consents.

I would suggested you to first create a dummy user, create the consents via Admin Console, then call:

```
GET /{realm}/users/{id}
```

inspect how the response looks, so that you know how the body content of the `POST /{realm}/users` should look like.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't allow to programatically mimic a user consent as users are already created... I searched in the API and there seems to be no endpoint to edit consents... Any other thoughts?